# Show "empty message" if filterBy returns empty

Tags: vue.js

I have a `v-repeat` instance and want to filter it by a search key.
If there is no match for the search, i want to be able to show a message:
*"There is no result that match your query"* or something like that.

Her is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/958/

So only if the filter returns no answers the message should be shown.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need computed properties. Basically like:

```
computed: {
  filteredThings: function () {
      return this.things.filter(function(thing){
          return thing.indexOf(this.searchQuery) > -1;
      }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dewey92/Lr9r2kfv/2/

I have also answered this type of question in [Vue.js empty filter results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743572/vue-js-empty-filter-results/32752611#32752611)

Comment: That is a great solution! Thanks man, interesting that this and the other question was asked at the same time. I searched but didnt find any. Thanks!

Comment: One thing though, it gets a whole lot messier when i want to search inside the entire object, then I'll have to loop through each key and that will be an aweful amount of looping...?

Comment: lol, yeah I found your question appeared just below the other question. no prob, mate. You can specify the key used to filter by `return thing['content'].indexOf(this.searchQuery) > -1;`