# Vue.js empty filter results

Tags: vue.js

In Vue, I have to filter through some data:

```
<input v-model="search">
<ul>
    <li v-repeat="photo in photos | filterBy search in 'name'">
        <img src="{{ photo.src }}" alt="{{ photo.name }}">
    </li>
    <li v-if="!photos.length">
        No results, sorry!
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I detect empty filter results and display an appropriate message to the user?

**EDIT**

I am currently doing the following which I feel is a hacky workaround:

HTML:

```
<input v-model="search">
<ul>
    <li v-repeat="photo in photos">
        <img src="{{ photo.src }}" alt="{{ photo.name }}">
    </li>
    <li v-if="!photos.length">
        No results, sorry!
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var v = new Vue({
    data: {
        allPhotos: [...],
        photos: [],
        search: '',
    },
    ready: function () {
        var filter = Vue.filter('filterBy');
        var self = this;
        this.$watch('search', function () {
            self.photos = filter(self.allPhotos, self.search, 'name');
        }, {
            immediate: true
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Vue 2.x (Update)

In Vue 2.x filters can now only be used, [as docs say](http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Filters), inside text interpolations:

> Vue 2.x filters can only be used inside mustache bindings. To achieve the same behavior inside directive bindings, you should use Computed properties instead.

You can achieve same behavior with JavaScript built-in `filter` method and computed property.

```html
<input v-model="searchQuery">

<span v-if="!filteredItems.length">No results.</span>

<ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredItems"></li>
</ul>
```

```js
computed: {
  filteredItems: function () {
    var self = this;
    return self.items.filter(function (item) {
      return item.indexOf(self.searchQuery) !== -1;
    })
  }
}
```

---

## Vue 1.x (Original Answer)

There are two ways at the moment. In all cases, template can look the same.

```html
<input v-model="searchQuery">

<span v-if="!filteredItems.length">No results.</span>

<ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredItems"></li>
</ul>
```

#### filterBy

Original `filterBy` method accessed via `$options`.

```js
computed: {
    filteredItems: function () {
        return this.$options.filters.filterBy(this.items, this.searchQuery);
    }
}
```

#### $eval

A little bit cleaner approach. Eval expression like you would do inside your template.

```js
computed: {
  filteredItems: function () {
    return this.$eval('items | filterBy searchQuery');
  }
}
```

Comment: Has this method been added to Vue.js recently? I know there have been a lot of changes to Vue.js recently and this option didn't appear to be available at the time! I'm accepting your answer because it is more relevant to 'now' though, good work!

Comment: You could use [`$eval`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-eval) to keep it a little cleaner and do like `return this.$eval('items | searchQuery')` and it would also allow you to chain more filters clearly.

Comment: It's highly probable. Version >1.0 has a lot of changes.

Comment: How can I specify the item property to filter with?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid with Vue 2.0. I believe Dewey Waspada's answer below is the best (and the only one that still works with 2.0).

Comment: I'd provide an example as well. Even if it'll be pretty much exactly what Dewey Waspada suggested.

Answer (score 9):

In HTML:

```
<input v-model="search">
<h4 v-if="!filteredPhotos.length">No results</h4>
<ul>
    <li v-for="photo in filteredPhotos">
        <img :src="photo.src" :alt="photo.name">
    </li>
</ul>
```

In JS, you need to use computed properties like this:

```
computed: {
  filteredPhotos: function () {
      return this.photos.filter(function(photo){
          return photo.name.indexOf(this.search) > -1;
      }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crswll/Lr9r2kfv/37/

Comment: Thanks, you've saved the day! BTW I do use `v-attr` for setting dynamic attributes but I thought for the purpose of demonstration to focus on the issue I had!

Comment: Visiting this question again after a while. This is definitely the right approach, especially with Vue 2.0 out.

Answer (score 2):

**This will only work with Vue 1.0, even then you should just be using a computed property. I'll leave this answer here just in case.**

---

You could use [`vm.$eval`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-eval) and a computed property to do this as well.

```
computed: {
  filteredItems: function () {
    return this.$eval('items | filterBy searchQuery');
  }
}
```

and use something like

```
<div v-if="filteredItems.length">
  <div v-for="item in filteredItems">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
  No results found!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML/CSS solution (just in case, if you still trying to fix it after 2 years)

```css
/* all list items are visible */
ul.that-list li { display: block; }

/* ...exept last one*/
ul.that-list li:last-child { display: none; }

/* but if last one is also first one ... means the only one */
ul.that-list li:first-child { display: block; }
```

```html
<h2>List with items</h2>
<ul class="that-list">
  <!-- here is your v-for with any filters you want -->
  <li>1 - Item is here</li>
  <li>2 - Another One Here</li>
  <li>3 - And anothe one</li>
  <!-- this is your message -->
  <li>(!message) There is no items... sorry</li>
</ul>

<h2>Empty</h2>
<ul class="that-list">
  <!-- v-for with no rendered items :c -->
  <li>(!message) There is no items... sorry</li>
</ul>
```

[Also codepen link here](https://codepen.io/vovchisko/pen/wpZqGP)